# Backwards compatibility when changing a Matlab struct

Tags: matlab

I'm extending an existing Matlab program with additional functionality. The original program uses a structure to represent a steady state point in a phase space, and this structure has 4 fields, like this:

```
oldstylepoint =
    kind: 'stst'
    parameter: [0.7846 1]
    x: -2.0010
    stability: [1x1 struct]
```

In my extension, I would like the structure to have 5 fields (i.e. one extra field). For most points, the field would just be empty, but for some special (bifurcation) points, it would contain some text (naming the kind of bifurcation occurring). So it would look like

```
newstylepoint =
    kind: 'stst'
    parameter: [0.7846 1]
    x: -2.0010
    stability: [1x1 struct]
    flag: 'hopf'
```

But now we run into a problem. Points like these are stored in arrays (branches), and most branches are built iteratively. So the existing programs has several subroutines doing things like

```
newbranch = [oldbranch, newpoint]
newbranch(1) = pointzero
newbranch(N+1) = newpoint
```

Now if the branch consists of "old style" points (with 4 fields) and I want to add a "new style" point (with 5 fields), Matlab gives a concatenation error.

So now my question: is there any way to tell Matlab that it should automatically create the missing fields when concatenating? Or is there another way to solve this problem in an elegant fashion?

(Of course, I could edit all existing subroutines to make sure all points they handle get the new field (set to '') if they don't have it already. But I would prefer changing as little existing code as possible. The other way around, ensuring all ingoing points (passed to existing routines as arguments) are "new style" would be difficult as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I know of no *elegant* way.

But yes you can do exactly as described in your post.

- Check if it exists with `isfield`.
- Add field if needed (use `setfield` or the short `.` notation)

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-5T8K1N/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-5T8K1N), it is not possible to do this without a moderate amount of  working-around.

Simplest and safest I could come up with is to initialize the new field in the old-style points, so all the `structs` in the `struct`-array have identical `fieldnames`, like so:

```
% Old-style points with only 4 fields
oldstylepoint = struct(...
    'kind', 'stst',...
    'parameter', [0.7846 1],...
    'x', -2.0010,...
    'stability', struct(...
        'test', 2)...
   );

% New-style points with 5 fields
newstylepoint = struct(...
    'kind', 'stst',...
    'parameter', [0.7846 1],...
    'x', -2.0010,...
    'stability', struct(...
    'test', 2),...
    'flag', 'hopf'...
);


% Example old-style branch
branch = [oldstylepoint; oldstylepoint]

% Before concatenation, initialize the new field in the branch
if ~isfield(branch, 'flag')
    [branch.flag] = deal([]); end

% Now we can concatenate without problems
[branch; newstylepoint]
```

You may also choose to use a tool for this (say [`catstruct`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842-catstruct) from the file exchange).

This will change the 3-line example above into a 1-line-and-more-robust solution in your code, but create a dependency to a 138-line piece of code with its own limitations (for example, MATLAB R13 and up, as stated in the function description).

Choose wisely :)